# How to import contacts from a delimited list?

Tags: applications, contacts, gmail

I use an Android phone, and recently I had to delete all my contacts because it was cluttered, and now I have to add all of them again. There are about 200 contacts, and I have them stored in a text file.

My list of contacts are in this format:

```
Henry Warren  | 9336982147
John  | 9012345678
William Lance Berkman | 9011423655
John Michael Stipe | 9123457819
```

How can I add these contacts to my phone? I have been trying for the past 2 hours to convert it into CSV format and *Import* it, but it's a painful job (and messy) because of the several fields. I've also tried various apps from the Play Store to try and import these, but none of them worked either.

There's probably an easier way to do this, so I figured I'd ask here. Any ideas?

Comment: If you've spent hours doing it the automated way, you didn't spend it typing in, and ended up with zero records. If you had spent it typing in, even at 30 seconds each, you'd be done by now. Sometimes manual is still better.

Comment: @wbogacz: I finally had to do it manually, but still, this is something I could use later. I suppose others *may* find this useful as well.